# Concurrent API Execution using Python MultiThreading, Nested if applicable

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpoolexecutor

API Triggers are not executing concurrently based on the TPS defined. There are 3 APIs, (Api1, api2, api3) that needs to be triggered as follows , along with maintaining the TPS associated with it.

- api1 triggers first concurrently based on the associated TPS set to it
- api2 triggers post completion of api1 (for those records, that got successfully processed from API)
- api3 triggers post completion of api2 (for those records, that got successfully processed from API)

The tps of the API should be following: api1_tps>= api2_tps >= api3_tps

For examples, if there are 1000 records, and tps is set 10 for all the 3 apis.
As and when api1 trigger completes for set of 10 records, api2 should trigger for these 10 records. similarly for api3 as well.

Please note: TPS is Transaction per second. I have tried below code.

Code is working but not working based on the TPS defined and the executions is also delayed. MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND_1 defines related TPS of API

```
def process_batch(records):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND_1,
                                   max_requests_per_second=MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND_1) as executor_A:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND_2,
                                       max_requests_per_second=MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND_2) as executor_B:
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND_3,
                                           max_requests_per_second=MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND_3) as executor_C:

                # for future_A in futures_A:
                for result_A in executor_A.map(api1_call, records):
                    if result_A is not None:
                        future_B = executor_B.submit(api2_call, result_A)
                        if future_B.result() is not None:
                            executor_C.submit(api3_call, future_B.result())
```